# Can't install tensorflow-text~=2.11.0

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip, conda

I got a warning  something like

```
warnings.warn(
No local packages or working download links found for tensorflow-text~=2.11.0
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('tensorflow-text~=2.11.0')
```

and if I run `pip install 'tensorflow-text~=2.11.0'`
I got :

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text~=2.11.0 (from versions: 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0, 2.10.0b2, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text~=2.11.0
```

*tensorflow-text 2.11.0 available on pypi*

and if I run `pip install tensorflow-text` it installs tensorflow-text 2.10.0 and downgrade the whole tensorflow to 2.10.0

Version Info:

1. OS: Windows 10
2. Environment:  Conda (miniconda3)
3. Python: 3.10.8
4. Tensorflow: 2.11

I've tried pip and conda-forge

Comment: You can try without the commas (')

Comment: tried that also

Comment: Download the whl based on python version from here-https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-text/2.11.0/#files and install

Comment: there's no distribution for windows

Comment: In that case there is no option but to build from source-https://github.com/tensorflow/text#build-from-source-steps

Comment: @SabbirHasan have you solved the problem?

Comment: Yes, We can't [see this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74632558/9885741)  @m-fuat

Comment: Do you have any good articles to build it locally on windows? To be honest, I am new to this stuff and couldn't build it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [their note](https://github.com/tensorflow/text#a-note-about-different-operating-system-packages), they have dropped building for Windows with v2.11.0. So, you'll need to build from source or seek a third-party build.

Comment: Do you know any 3rd-party build available?

Comment: @pav no, I do not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should install an older version of python,like 3.9.* .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar a problem and it seems like you need to first install `tensorflow-text` as follows

`!pip install -q -U "tensorflow-text==2.11.*"`

This installation will raise dependency errors but its ok.

Then import `tensorflow` and `tensorflow_text`.

Answer (score -3):

I think you should run

```
pip install tensorflow-text==2.11.0
```

without any quotes or swung dash

Comment: doesn't work that too